# What is the most efficient way to reference another table from the first?

Tags: mysql, database-design

So I have one table with cultures in it. These cultures need to be associated with another table, with an organization and all the information about that organization.

Currently, I have a foreign key setup, however the culture table seems to now require an organization UID- I don't want that, I merely want the information in the culture table's org_id column (the UID of the organization, a foreign key to another table) to update/delete if the UID does change, not to require a the organization's UID.

In addition, what is the most efficient way to associate more than one foreign key (i.e. organizational UIDs) with one culture?

Basically, the culture table looks like this:

```
culture  |  org_id
_________________
American | 1 (reference to organization database)
```

And the organization table looks like this:

```
UID (same as org_id above) | blah blah blah (address, city, state, etc)
_______________________________________________________________________
1 |Detroit |Michigan |etc
```

And I want to be able to have multiple org_ids, all references to organization table orgs, under one culture. I also want to be able to create cultures WITHOUT specifying an org_id.

Comment: "I want to be able to have multiple org_ids, all references to organization table orgs, under one culture" - why don't you add them as separate records (with the same value for culture field)?

Comment: "create cultures WITHOUT specifying an org_id" - use NULL in the org_id field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the relationship backwards. Instead of having `org_id` in the `Culture` table, you should add a `culture_id` column to the `Organization` table. That column should have a foreign key that references the `Culture` table.

**EDIT**: The diagram below is based on the discussion from the comments.

[image]

Comment: What benefits does this have? Also, would this allow for multiple cultures?

Comment: @JakeSmith "What benefits does this have?" It's the right way to model the relationship you've described. Now, if an Organization can have multiple cultures, then you have a many-to-many relationship and you'll want to introduce a third table to resolve that. Something like `Organization_Culture_Xref`, which would consist of two foreign keys, one pointing to `Organization` and one pointing to `Culture`.

Comment: An organization can have multiple cultures, in addition, there are two other columns with multiple values, services and categories.

So what you are telling me is that I should have a total of 7 tables?

Comment: @JakeSimth Yes. You've got it.

Comment: What precisely would organization_culture_xref contain? Just the two foreign keys?

Comment: @JakeSmith Yes. The table should have a composite primary key consisting two columns: `org_id` and `culture_id`. Each of those columns should have a foreign key relationship with their parent table. Nothing else should be in the xref table.

Comment: @JakeSmith: I've added a diagram to the answer to illustrate what we've discussed here.

Comment: Thank you. Also, I wanted to let you know that my supervisor, after looking at my database structure, gave me similar changes!